# Velodyne driver installation

Tags: ros, catkin, velodyne-driver, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install the drivers for Velodyne 32E. I downloaded the folder from https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne and then I am typing cmake ../ to build it.

I am getting an error:

--from catkin.environment_cache import generate_environment_script

--ImportError: No module named catkin.environment_cache

I have installed catkin_pkg using pip.

What should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213268/velodyne-driver-installation/) by [Kostas07](https://answers.ros.org/users/23116/kostas07/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is not the way to build any ROS package, including the Velodyne driver.

ROS packages are built using [catkin_make](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/commands/catkin_make), or some similar tool. See the [catkin documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin), many tutorials and API documents are listed there.

**EDIT**: start with the first three catkin tutorials:

- [creating a workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace)
- [creating a package](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/CreatingPackage)
- [using a workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace)

That should teach you how build this or any other ROS package.

**EDIT2**: There are [instructions for installing ROS on OSX](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source), but I have only used Linux. OSX does not look easy, but some people do successfully use it.

Those instructions recommend homebrew rather than macports.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kostas07](https://answers.ros.org/users/23116/kostas07/) on 2015-07-10**:
Thank you for your reply!
I am really new with all these. I haven't use ROS before. I though that by installing catkin and catkin_pkg, I would be okay. Apparently I am not. Could you please help me by enumerating a few steps that I have to follow? My goal is to convert pcap files to pcd files.

**Comment by [Kostas07](https://answers.ros.org/users/23116/kostas07/) on 2015-07-10**:
I forgot to mention that I am using a mac.

**Comment by [Kostas07](https://answers.ros.org/users/23116/kostas07/) on 2015-07-11**:
Thank you again! I did as you said and I found a problem installing pcl_ros:
$catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
...
Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.....

I have Eigen3 installed with macports. What should I do?